# How to create a unique form using multiple entities fields in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to create a form using some fields from multiple entities. I have all the distinct entites needed already created and i am not using form classes. I need to know how to do to render a form and handle its data so i can save them to the correct tables in my database.

Here is a part of my controller in charge of doing that

```
public function createPublicSpaceAction() {
    //My entities
    $Room = new Room();
    $GuestList = new GuestList();
    $Guest = new Guest();

    //I need to know what to do from here

    return $this -> render('AcmeUserBundle:Default:Forms/createPublicSpace.html.twig', array());
}
```

I kept trying to find a solution and i came up with the idea that one form needs one entity. So maybe the solution would be to merge those entities in one so i can build the form easily. I would then have to persist data to corresponding tables. But i can't think of how to merge entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a temporary solution. For those who want to know, I manually created an entity that looks like a merge of all the entity I need. This new entity has no link with Doctrine therefore it cannot create a table. Its goal is simply to allow me to build up a form and be able to manipulate data through that form. I then assign all data submitted to corresponding entities fields and persist them to the database.

Once again i know this is not the best solution. But for some reasons I won't tell, it is for me at this moment. I hope this can help some that are in the same situation than me and do not hesitate to post links that could help or better ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly recommended to use form classes http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes

They are designed to save time and make a lot of things just easier.

However to answer your question consider the following. Your action needs to handel a post request. So catch the request object with the post data:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function createPublicSpaceAction(Request $request)
```

Then get a form builder intance and create the form:

```
$builder = $this->createFormBuilder();

$builder->add('floor', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Room floor',
        'data' => $room->getFloor()
));
```

add as much form fields as you need. There are several built-in field types: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#built-in-field-types

Create the form:

```
$form = $builder->getForm();
```

Pass the form to your template:

```
return $this -> render('AcmeUserBundle:Default:Forms/
                        createPublicSpace.html.twig', array(
    'roomForm' = $form
));
```

To get posted data within your action:

```
if ('POST' == $request->getMethod()) {
    $data = $request->request->get("form");
}
```

And in your template you can render the form by yourself or let twig do the job:

```
{{ form_widget(form.floor)}}
```

So this are the most importend things to mention. However you should go through http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html They actually tell you everything I wrote down.

Good luck ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help but i still don't know how to build up one form that includes fields taken from different entities that have nothing in common.